# Form InitializeComponent taking a long time to get started

Tags: .net, winforms, optimization

A while ago my app has started taking a long time to show the main window. I've put a `System.Diagnostics.Profiler` in the form constructor as follows:

```
Private m_profiler As New System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
Public Sub New()
  ' This call is required by the designer.
  m_profiler.Restart()
  InitializeComponent()
  m_profiler.Stop()
  Rhino.RhinoApp.WriteLine("InitializeComponent() took {0}ms", m_profiler.ElapsedMilliseconds)

  ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
  Rhino.RhinoApp.WriteLine("InitializeComponent() init took {0}ms", m_profiler.ElapsedMilliseconds)

  Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
  .....yada yada yada
```

The results are:

```
InitializeComponent() init took 2572ms
InitializeComponent() took 2837ms
```

So almost all the time is spend just calling the `InitializeComponent()` method, which *I assume* is because of jitting. Is there something I can do to accelerate the showing of the main form?

Would it make sense to show the form without any controls, load those controls in a background thread so they get compiled and then instantiate new controls on the UI thread and add them to the form?

Is there something I can do to find out what really is taking up all this time?

My app is a pure .NET plug-in to an unmanaged C++ desktop application which exposes a .NET SDK. It is currently running as a 64-bit application on Windows 7.

Comment: No, calling a method takes a fraction of a nanosecond.  You'd better find out why initializing Rhino.RhinoApp takes so long.  Use a good profiler.

Comment: Thanks Hans, Rhino.RhinoApp is the main application which is already well up and running by the time I get around to loading my plug-in. It also doesn't matter at all whether I print the profiling results or not, it's the same ~3 second wait.